# tkinter GUI (Lights not displaying to my window)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Three lights operate with radio button

Can anyone help me to figure out the cause? The below code gives no error but no output:( On my root other icons appear (which is not included here) but the below portion of code not works?

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

color = StringVar()

 radio_red = Radiobutton(frame, text="Red", bg="red", variable= color, value="R", command= on_RadioChange)
 radio_red.grid(row=10, column=1)

 radio_yellow = Radiobutton(frame, text="Yellow", bg="yellow", variable= color, value="Y", command= on_RadioChange)               
 radio_yellow.grid(row = 10, column = 2)

 radio_green = Radiobutton(frame, text="Green", bg="green", variable= color, value="G", command= on_RadioChange)
 radio_green.grid(row = 10, column = 3)

 canvas = Canvas(root, width=450, height=300, bg="white")
 canvas.pack()

 oval_red = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 110, 110, fill="white")
 oval_yellow = canvas.create_oval(120, 10, 220, 110, fill="white")
 oval_green = canvas.create_oval(230, 10, 330, 110, fill="white")

  color.set('R')
  canvas.itemconfig(oval_red, fill="red")
        
  root.mainloop()       

def on_RadioChange():
        color = color.get()

        if color == 'R':
            canvas.itemconfig(oval_red, fill="red")
            canvas.itemconfig(oval_yellow, fill="white")
            canvas.itemconfig(oval_green, fill="white")
        elif color == 'Y':
            canvas.itemconfig(oval_red, fill="white")
            canvas.itemconfig(oval_yellow, fill="yellow")
            canvas.itemconfig(oval_green, fill="white")
        elif color == 'G':
            canvas.itemconfig(oval_red, fill="white")
            canvas.itemconfig(oval_yellow, fill="white")
            canvas.itemconfig(oval_green, fill="green")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably understand how to use classes, but here is an example on how to use classes with your given code.

```
from tkinter import *

class TrafficLights:

    def value(self):

        root = Tk()

        frame = Frame(root)
        frame.pack()

        self.color = StringVar()

        radio_red = Radiobutton(frame, text="Red", bg="red", variable= self.color, value="R", command= self.on_RadioChange)
        radio_red.grid(row=10, column=1)

        radio_yellow = Radiobutton(frame, text="Yellow", bg="yellow", variable= self.color, value="Y", command= self.on_RadioChange)               
        radio_yellow.grid(row = 10, column = 2)

        radio_green = Radiobutton(frame, text="Green", bg="green", variable= self.color, value="G", command= self.on_RadioChange)
        radio_green.grid(row = 10, column = 3)

        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=450, height=300, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.oval_red = self.canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 110, 110, fill="white")
        self.oval_yellow = self.canvas.create_oval(120, 10, 220, 110, fill="white")
        self.oval_green = self.canvas.create_oval(230, 10, 330, 110, fill="white")

        self.color.set('R')
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_red, fill="red")
        
        root.mainloop()

    def on_RadioChange(self):
        color = self.color.get()

        if color == 'R':
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_red, fill="red")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_yellow, fill="white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_green, fill="white")
        elif color == 'Y':
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_red, fill="white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_yellow, fill="yellow")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_green, fill="white")
        elif color == 'G':
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_red, fill="white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_yellow, fill="white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_green, fill="green")

a = TrafficLights()
a.value()
```

The main mistake was that you were not using `self` and did not call the method `value()`. So I fixed all those. So if you dont want to call `value()` then you would use change `def value(self)` with def `__init__(self):` so that now you dont have to call `a.value()`. I recommend you study more about OOP before proceeding to classes with python and tkinter.

**UPDATE:**

There is nothing much wrong, just rearrrange the code and change the `color` inside function to `colors` or something else, completed code would be:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def on_RadioChange():
        colors = color.get()

        if colors == 'R':
            canvas.itemconfig('oval_red', fill="red")
            canvas.itemconfig('oval_yellow', fill="white")
            canvas.itemconfig('oval_green', fill="white")
        elif colors == 'Y':
            canvas.itemconfig('oval_red', fill="white")
            canvas.itemconfig('oval_yellow', fill="yellow")
            canvas.itemconfig('oval_green', fill="white")
        elif colors == 'G':
            canvas.itemconfig('oval_red', fill="white")
            canvas.itemconfig('oval_yellow', fill="white")
            canvas.itemconfig('oval_green', fill="green")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

color = StringVar()

radio_red = Radiobutton(frame, text="Red", bg="red", variable=color, value="R", command=on_RadioChange)
radio_red.grid(row=10, column=1)

radio_yellow = Radiobutton(frame, text="Yellow", bg="yellow", variable=color, value="Y", command=on_RadioChange)               
radio_yellow.grid(row = 10, column = 2)

radio_green = Radiobutton(frame, text="Green", bg="green", variable=color, value="G", command=on_RadioChange)
radio_green.grid(row = 10, column = 3)

canvas = Canvas(root, width=450, height=300, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 110, 110, fill="white",tag='oval_red')
canvas.create_oval(120, 10, 220, 110, fill="white",tag='oval_yellow')
canvas.create_oval(230, 10, 330, 110, fill="white",tag='oval_green')

color.set('R')
canvas.itemconfig('oval_red', fill="red")
    
root.mainloop()
```

Why changing `color` to `colors`? When your using `color` your actually referencing to `color` with `color`, which will raise an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'color' referenced before assignment`(since its inside of function?), so to get rid of this, just rename(only in this case). Is this the best way of doing this? I dont think so, there are some useless variables that you could get rid of here.

Comment: this works, but this opens a separate window. not added to my main window

Comment: @mayaali Running this same code, I just get one window. I dont see a possibility for one more window.

Comment: I have now removed the class from code. Now can you solve the problem of the color variable?